# Combinatoric Explanation for $\tbinom{n}{1} + \tbinom{n}{2} \ldots + \tbinom{n}{n} = 2^n - 1$?

Tags: combinatorics

Via induction, we can show that:
$$\tbinom{n}{1} + \tbinom{n}{2} \ldots + \tbinom{n}{n} \ \ = \ \ 2^n - 1$$

When $n = 2$, write $\tbinom{2}{1} + \tbinom{2}{2} = 3$.  Suppose that the equality holds up to $n$.  At $n + 1$, write:

\begin{align*}
\tbinom{n+1}{1} + \tbinom{n+1}{2} \ldots + \tbinom{n+1}{n} + \tbinom{n+1}{n+1} \ \ 
& = \ \ \tbinom{n}{0} + \tbinom{n}{1} \ldots + \tbinom{n}{n-1} \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + \tbinom{n}{1} + \tbinom{n}{2} \ldots + \tbinom{n}{n} + \tbinom{n+1}{n+1} \\
& = \ \ 2 [ \, 2^n - 1 \, ] + 1 \\
& = \ \ 2^{n+1} - 1
\end{align*}
In the above, we used the identity $\tbinom{n}{k} + \tbinom{n}{k+1} = \tbinom{n+1}{k+1}$.  However, what is the combinatoric explanation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a set of $n$ elements, then we find the number of nonempty subsets. It is clearly $2^n - 1$ (we can choose to include an element or not, thus for n elements, we have $2^n$ choices, but we subtract 1 for the empty set)

Now, suppose we instead solve the problem by looking at nonempty subsets of size $k$. Then we can create $\binom{n}{k}$ many subsets of size $k$, so we have $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}$ subsets. As these two quantities are equal, $\sum_{k =1}^n\binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 1$

Comment: After some thoughts, this is the one I came up with.  But all others are interesting too.  TY

Answer (score 2):

Claim:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\tbinom{n}i=2^n$$

To see this consider number of ways to separate a group of $n$ people into $2$ groups, group $A$ and group $B$, each person is assigned to exactly one group, where we are alright with a group being empty.

One way to compute this quantity is to consider let me choose $i$ people and assign them to group $A$ and assign the rest to group $B$, which gives the left hand side formula.

Another way to compute this is to ask each person which group they would like to join. Each person has $2$ options, hence $2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

On the right hand side, we have "number of ways to choose $k+1$ objects from $n+1$ objects".

Now,  there are two disjoint ways of doing this:

1) Label one of the $n$ objects as "not to be taken". This cannot be chosen now. So all of the $k+1$ objects must be chosen from the rest of the set. This is done in $\binom{n}{k+1}$ ways.

2) That same object now can be labelled as "has to be taken". Now, from the remaining $n$ objects, only $k$ need to be chosen. Hence, this is done in $\binom nk$ ways.

Now, you can see where the equality comes from in this part.

The combinatoric explanation for the main equality itself comes from choosing proper subsets of a given set. The number of proper subsets is $2^n-1$, since every element can be chosen or not chosen independently of the other, giving $2$ choices for each of $n$ objects, but the whole set must be excluded as it is not proper, so that is $2^n-1$.

On the other hand, a subset of size $k$ is just choosing $k$ elements out of $n$, where $k <n$. This can be done in $\binom nk$ ways, and summing over possible $k$ gives the left hand side. Equality follows.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we flip a coin $n$ times. There are a total of $2^n$ (ordered) possible outcomes. As we can get a head or a tail for each trial, giving two choices for each slot, and there are $n$ of those. Hence by multiplication principle the total amount of outcomes is $(2)(2)...(2)=2^n$.

Now how many of those outcomes contain exactly $k$ heads? Well, there are $n$ slots, and we need to choose $k$ of them to put $H's$ in (and fill the rest of the slots with $T's$). It doesn't matter the order we choose the slots in. Nor does it matter the order that we put $H's$ in the chosen spots, nor does it matter the order we decide to put the $T's$ in the remaining spots. Hence once the slots are chosen, the outcome is pretty much already determined.

So it follows there are ${n \choose k}$ outcomes with exactly $k$ heads.

We can have $0$ or $1$ or $2$ ....or $n$ heads. That's it, that accounts for all the possible outcomes. So it must be that,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}=2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at binary numbers with $n$ digits ($n$ zeroes is also an $n$-digit binary number). We want to count all these numbers.

The first way is $2^n$.

The second way is $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i$, where $a_i$ is the amount of numbers with $i$ ones. However, $a_i={n \choose i} $.

So $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}=2^n$.

So $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose i}=2^n-1$.